# Override build through configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

Is it possible to override an existing package's build script, or in this case [vscode-with-extensions](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/editors/vscode/with-extensions.nix#L68). I know how to override an option, which in this package is `vscodeExtensions`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465738/override-scripts-in-nix-derivations) seems to show one approach, but I don't seem to see where to override `runCommand` in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The override function can only change the inputs to the function. It is not possible to modify arbitrary subexpressions.

Assuming you just want to add an extension to your configuration, it seems to me that you don't need to actually modify the whole expression that invokes `runCommand`.

Here's how you can override the `vscodeExtensions` argument:

```
let
  overlay = self: super: {
    vscode-with-extensions = super.vscode-with-extensions.override {
      vscodeExtensions =
        super.vscode-utils.extensionsFromVscodeMarketplace [
          {
            name = "vscode-hie-server";
            publisher = "alanz";
            version = "0.0.19";
            sha256 = "0x0cs7c5q90p1ffig2wb5v21z3yj3p2chgpvbnlm4gfsnw7qpfzr";
          }
        ] ++ with super.vscode-extensions; [
          bbenoist.Nix
        ];
    };
  };
in
# NixOS:
# { nixpkgs.overlays = [ overlay ]; }
#
# or nix-build:
(import <nixpkgs> {
  overlays = [ overlay ];
}).vscode-with-extensions
```

If you want this snippet as a NixOS configuration, comment the nix-build part, uncomment the NixOS part and you have a module you can add to your NixOS `imports`.

Disclaimer: this is not really my setup, I'm just checking it out. At least the Nix part seems to work.